# generate a list of URL links for files in folder [javascript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to generate list for each file in folder.For example if I have following files in specific folder

- sample_picture1.jpg
- sample_picture2.jpg

I want to generate URL links as follows

- [0] -  src='http://localhost/path/sample_picture1.jpg'
- [1] -  src='http://localhost/path/sample_picture2.jpg'

---

Currently I created it as like this.

json method to find files in a folder

```
    public JsonResult filesinfolder()
    {
        string salesFTPPath = "folder_path";

        DirectoryInfo salesFTPDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(salesFTPPath);

        IEnumerable<string> files = salesFTPDirectory.GetFiles()
          .Where(f => f.Extension == ".xls" || f.Extension == ".xml" || f.Extension == ".jps" || f.Extension == ".jpg" || f.Extension == ".jpeg" || f.Extension == ".png")
          .OrderBy(f => f.Name)
          .Select(f => f.Name);

        return Json(files, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

script to get files

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("filesinfolder", "Home")',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { onSuccess(data); },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {}
    });
});

var onSuccess = function (data) {

};
```

So I want to take the result to `onSuccess`  as list of URLs (for files in a folder).

Comment: Is there any specific reason your using ajax for this (as opposed to just passing the collection of files to the view and generating the links)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Since I need to do once page load I'm using ajax , no other reason , is there any other better way to that ?

Comment: Would certainly be simpler to just pass the collection of urls to the view (ideally using a view model property but it could be a `ViewBag` property). What are you wanting to do with them? - create `<img>` elements?

Comment: I'm not clear what the problem/question is. Does this code not work? If not, what is it doing, what's the error, etc.?

Comment: yeah! exactly!   @StephenMuecke  I want to generate list of `<img style='height:160px' src='http://localhost/path/sample_picture1.jpg'>`   can I do this if I pass the collection of urls to the view ?

Comment: @AlanMcBee code is working , but I want to customize this results that getting to `onSuccess` as `<img>` elements

Comment: Sure. Just generate the collection in the GET method, assign it to a view model property, and in the view use a `@foreach(string url in Model.Images) { <img scr="@url" height=".." width=".." /> }` (note you will probably need `Url.Content()` to generate the correct url)

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you refer me example to generate the collection in the GET method ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke has the right answer if you want his Razor C# to go into the View, and not use Ajax at all. If you want to use Ajax and javascript in the onSuccess function, you would do something similar, using something like `$.each(data, function(item) { $("#mydiv").append("<img>").attrib("src", item); } );` NOTE: this syntax is not guaranteed to work, just get you close.

Comment: @kez, No different that you doing with your current `IEnumerable<string> files = ....` query. Just assign that collection to a view model property (or `ViewBag` property)

Comment: @StephenMuecke currently I'm doing it like that noh ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you ajax call is executing on `document.ready`, there seems no need to use ajax, and you could simplify this by passing the collection of urls to the view. Assuming your using a view model, add a property (say) `IEnumerable<string> ImageUrls { get; set; }` (alternatively you could assign the collection to a `ViewBag` property)

In the GET method that generates the view

```
// get the files
IEnumerable<string> files = salesFTPDirectory.GetFiles().Where(....
// build urls
model.ImageUrls = new List<string>();
foreach (string name in files)
{
  model.ImageUrls.Add(Url.Content("~/path") + "/" + name);
}
return View(model);
```

And in the view

```
@foreach(string url in Model.ImageUrls)
{
  <img src="@url" height="100" width="100" />
}
```

Assuming the file names you query is generating are `sample_picture1.jpg` and `sample_picture2.jpg`, then this will generate

```
<img src="/path/sample_picture1.jpg" ... />
<img src="/path/sample_picture2.jpg" ... />
```

If you do want to do this using ajax, then generate the urls as above in the `filesinfolder()` method and return them, then in the `success` callback

```
success: function (data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, item) {
    var img = $('<img>').attr('src', item);
    $(someElement).append(img);
  });
}
```

Side note: Its slightly confusing that you have `string salesFTPPath = "folder_path";` but you want to generate `.../path/...` and not `.../folder_path/...` (I assume one or the other is a typo), but in anycase, this won't work once you publish your app. You will need to use `Server.MapPath()` to generate the correct path to the folder.

Comment: Sorry my mistake `path` and `folder_path` are same , I'll try this thanks lot

Comment: what are the model properties I should use `public string ImageUrls { get; set; }` or `List` ?

Comment: Sorry - didn't format the code correctly - use `IEnumerable<string>` (or `List<string>`) - see update in first paragraph

Comment: I just changed `model.ImageUrls.Add(Url.Content("~/path") + "/" + name);` to `model.ImageUrls.Add(Url.Content(Server.MapPath("path") + "/" + name));`  then I put a html tag to grab value like this `<li id="idd"></li>` then I put an alert like this `alert($('#idd').append(img));` then I can see `[object][object]` twice not a image URL noh?

Comment: For the moment, keep it as `model.ImageUrls.Add(Url.Content("~/path") + "/" + name);` - you not using `Server.MapPath("path")` correctly but we can sort that later. Have you decided to go with the javascript/ajax option? But I cannot understand what your actually doing. If your have added the images to the model, why are you using javascript, and what is `img`? And you need to remove the `alert()` - it makes no sense to 'alert' a function.

Comment: You should also confirm the values your generating - it should be `"/path/sample_picture1.jpg"`, `"/path/sample_picture2.jpg"` etc

Comment: I just decided to come up with javascript/ajax option. So I added html tag `<li id="idd"></li>` to grab values then in ajax success event changed like this `$('#idd').append(img);` then I can see preview [like this](http://i.imgur.com/nLWWqqA.jpg) in my viewpage  , once I click one of that that broken thumbnails I can get an image path like this `http://localhost:49669/Home/sampleimage1.jpg`

Comment: Then you not generating the correct path (where did `/Home/` come from?). Add a `console.log(item);` and check the output. Aslo add a `console.log(img); statement and inspect the value of the `src` property

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98222/discussion-between-kez-and-stephen-muecke).